# Thymeleaf abnormal behavior with null value

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Mongodb Document like:

```
Document document = new Document()
document.append("_id", 1);
document.append("isTrue", true); //this is optional
```

that how I am printing it in Thymeleaf.

```
<td th:text="${document.isTrue}"></td>
```

So, since isTrue is optional, sometimes isTrue exists sometimes not. When document.isTrue exists it works fine but when not exists Thymeleaf gives the error

```
Exception evaluating SpringEL expression: "document.isTrue"
```

while i was expecting it should print null as it is since mongodb document returns null when no key matching exists for given value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think in this case you should use:

```
<td th:text="${document['isTrue']}" />
```

It looks like the `.` operator is more strict than `['key']` when accessing a map.  Alternatively, you could also do:

```
<td th:text="${document.get('isTrue')}" />
```